# How to fix java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: android, flutter

I try to access the file I had downloaded from flutter app and save it to external storage. I call the file and use it in java part but it show this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/abc.xyz.qwe/files/mobilenet.tflite

I have tried to grant permission before call the file but it still not work (The file is exist, i have checked).

Comment: `I call the file and use it in java part but it show this error:`. What is 'calling' a file? Show the code that causes the errror. In your post. Further you dont need any permission for that path.

Answer (score 0):

You start the file name with a slash. What directory is the file located in? If the storage folder is not in the root directory (`/`), then you won't be able to find the file. If storage is in the same place as the java file you're running, you should remove the first `/`